# Copying a List of T

Tags: vb.net, list, visual-studio-2012, copy, addrange

I am using VS2012, vb.net.

If I have a list of type t, and I wish to copy this to another list, the following code works:

```
list2.Clear()
list2.AddRange(list1)
```

However, if the first list of t has another list of type t2 inside it, this above code does not work.

Can I please have some help to copy the contents of a list of t to another list where the list of t has another list of t2 inside it.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly means `first list of t has another list of type t2 inside it`? Could you provide some working example code? Maybe you're looking for a deep copy of the list.

Comment: Agreed.  I think your confusion comes from not understanding value types vs. reference types as well as shallow copying vs. deep copying.  However, it's hard to say for sure without a clear example of what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
However, if the first list of t has another list of type t2 inside it, this above code does not work.
```

It *does* work, but it does [a shallow copy, not a deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).

Let's say you want to do a deep copy of a `List(Of List(Of Integer))`. You can do it like this:

```
Dim list1 As List(Of List(Of Integer))

*Populate list 1*

Dim copy = list1.Select(Function(innerList) innerList.ToList).ToList
```

Now you have to independent lists, because you copy each inner list with `ToList`, and also copy the outer list with `ToList`. Note that if you had reference type objects instead of integers in the inner list, you would also need to clone each individual object to do a deep copy.